# How to implement "check all" functionality on different pages that checks only current page data in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with a large number of records paginated with the help of data tables. The first header column is a select all checkbox and every row has its own checkbox.

I would like to have following functionality in my table:

1) User can navigate through the table and randomly select/deselect checkboxes.

2) Clicking on "select all" checkbox in the thead should check/uncheck all the currently visible records only.

3) **The "select all" button should maintain a state(checked/unchecked) for different pages of datatables.** E.g. - if the user clicks select all on page 1 and navigates to next page, the Select all checkbox should be deselected and clicking it again would check all the rows in this page only while the previously selected checkboxes stays unaffected.

So far I have the following code to handle check selection:

```
$('#selectAllCheck').click(function(e) {

    var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
    var currentRows = $('#myTable tbody tr');

    $.each(currentRows, function(){
        $(this).find(':checkbox[name=statusCheckbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', chk);
        });
    });
  });
```

I am aware of the `_('tr', {"filter":"applied"});` function but it just returns all the rows to me. I don't know why.

I have implemented (1) and (2) already with the above code and it works fine. The only problem is the behaviour of "Select all" functionality on different pages. I looked up at datatables.net but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what i end up implementing for my requirement. Although not perfect, but this code nicely implements "select all" column in datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "fnDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
            //managing the "Select all" checkbox
            // everytime the table is drawn, it checks if all the 
            //checkboxes are checked and if they are, then the select all
            // checkbox in the table header is selected
            var allChecked = true;
            $('#mytable tbody tr').each(function() {
                $(this).find(':checkbox[name=statusCheckbox]').each(function(){
                    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                        allChecked = false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            $('#selectAllCheck').prop('checked', allChecked);
        },
        });

// This is to stop datatable to sort the column on checking the checkbox
$('thead').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.type == 'checkbox') {
        e.stopPropogation();
    }
});

// Click handler for select all checkbox that checks the rows on current view only
$('#selectAllCheck').click(function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
    var currentRows = $('#mytable tbody tr');
    $.each(currentRows, function(){
        $(this).find(':checkbox[name=statusCheckbox]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', chk);
        });
    });
  });
```

});

Comment: i am stuck on third features.

Comment: Yes, the code was working fine, was tested well and is now in production :). If you are unable to implement 3rd feature, then most probably the problem is somewhere around your fdnDrawCallback

Comment: thats grt then... i am implementing this is in JSF and also new to for jquery.... :(

Comment: This solution worked fine and i put the table in form to submit selected rows when i submit the form it only submit current page inputs not all pages inputs how can i get all selected inputs values when i submit the form?

Answer (score 2):

I use function "fnGetNodes" so the code is:

```
  var table = $('#your-table-id ').DataTable();

  jQuery('#your-table-id .group-checkable').change(function () {      

            var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");

            jQuery( "input", table.fnGetNodes() ).each(function(){                  
                 if(checked)
                 {                                                                         
                    $(this).attr("checked", true);                                                                                                                    
                 }
                 else
                 {                                                                                               
                    $(this).attr("checked", false);                        
                 }
            })                
  });
```

where .group-checkable is class for checkbox in table head to select all rows

Answer (score 1):

You could use the drawback function for this, to save the pageNumber and the checkbox status in an array or something, and check or uncheck:

Like this: (Care, this fires not only on page change)

```
$("#example").dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
        ....  
    }
});
```

or width this:

```
$("#example").on("page", function() {
   ...
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the pointer reyaner. fnDrawCallback did the trick. The second snippet you gave wont work in my case as it will execute before moving to next page.